# How to recover deleted files from [formatted] FAT32/NTFS drive in Linux?

Tags: linux, file-recovery

Is there like EasyRecovery for Linux? Free open source command-line based software strongly preferred.

Expecting something like:

```
$ fat32_recovery --some-arcane-options dump.img dir/
Recovery in progress...
    ~ILE1.TXT -> dir/XILE1.TXT
    ~IR1 -> dir/XIR1/
    ~IR1/ololo.txt -> dir1/XIR1/ololo.txt
    ~IR1/kekeke.avi -> dir1/XIR/kekeke.avi [damaged 10%]
    goodfile.txt -> dir1/goodfile.txt
```

Is there special things for jpg photos or documents (like in EasyRecovery)?

There are numerous step-by-step recovery GUI tools for Windows, I'm looking for console-based ones targeted for power users.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), which works natively on Linux.  It works with all Windows and Linux filesystems.  If the filesystem itself is damaged beyond what PhotoRec can handle, you can also use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (from the same company) which can repair and recover an entire filesystem if possible.  Both of these tools are free, open source, and cross platform.  From the website:

> PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying data,
>   so it will still work even if your media's file system has been
>   severely damaged or reformatted.

Alternatively, you might have some luck using [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) under Wine.  From the entry in [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=11256&iTestingId=22379), it appears as though it works with Windows-based filesystems (e.g. NTFS/FAT32), but not Linux-based ones (e.g. Ext3, XFS).

Comment: Oh, forgot about PhotoRec. Hope it will work. But Recuva = fail. Looks like just yet another windows file recovery GUI tool that even can't dig into drive image.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that you were working with an image file.  In that case, yeah, you can scrap Recuva.  I've used it on Windows with some success, but that was only on a live hard drive.